# What is meaning of comment 'Go Horse' in coding? Is it some sort of process?

Tags: javascript, coding-style, comments

I have read some developers quoting GoHorse value in their comments; mostly in javascript. It is mostly constant and long value.,

I am unable to understand; what it mean to Gohorse?

```
var a = 8888888888888; // GoHorse
```

Comment: It means some developer left a meaningful comment intended to help future devs understand what the code was doing. *insert sarcasm here*

Comment: @fath it's just a _joke_ to mean they used a _quick & dirty_ solution instead of writing _right_ code. It may be a magic number (it doesn't matter its value), a special _safe_ value used instead of _right_ one (because annoying to calculate or to find). It may be a terrible hack...anything like that.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti
Oh. never thought about that. Is it some phrase used in Core English speaking areas?

Comment: I'm not native speaker, I have no idea about its usage in  "real language"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Go Horse Process is like a horse race:
You line up on the start, then BAM! you're racing down the track, without looking up (or, in fact, any direction), just hurry to finish before the deadline.

It is simple: Does it compile? ==> Task done.

See 1: https://gist.github.com/banaslee/4147370#file-xgh-en-txt
See 2: https://www.facebook.com/gohorseprocess.extremegohorse

Note: This is some kind of joke, of course, a funny name like spaghetti code, for a bad-bad habit.